# "CSS-like" fallback cascading data in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to implement a price fallback system in SQL server. I'd like to have a set of increasingly specific prices (eg: by region, store, warehouse, etc.) for a product, that may or may not be defined, and be able to select the most specific prices (ie: the one with most parameters defined) in a report.

For example, I might have the following data:

```
 Region
--------
   1
   2

 Store  
--------
   1
   2
   3

Product | Region | Store | Price
--------------------------------
  Foo   | NULL   | NULL  |  1.0
  Foo   | 1      | NULL  |  2.0
  Foo   | 1      | 1     |  2.5
  Foo   | 1      | 2     |  2.3
```

So if I wanted to know the price for product Foo...

- in Region 1, Store 1 = 2.5
- in Region 1, Store 3 = 2.0 *(Store 3 is not defined explicitly in the data, so the result comes from the NULL store for Region 1)*
- in Region 2, Store 4 = 1.0 *(Region 2 is not defined explicitly in the data, so the result comes from the NULL region)*

For the sake of simplicity, I can assume that the Store is always more specific than the region, and a store can only exist in one region.

A schema for this data would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Prices(
    ID      int   IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Product int   NOT NULL,
    Region  int   NULL,
    Store   int   NULL,
    Price   money NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Prices PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID ASC),
    CONSTRAINT IX_Prices UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (Product ASC, Region ASC, Store ASC)
)
```

Aside from crunching this data in code, how can I query this table for a list of effective prices for every product, based on (Region, Store)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, you guys are trying way too hard.  Here's the easy way: use the COALESCE command, which takes the first non-null value.

```
SELECT COALESCE(st.Price, rg.Price, gn.Price) AS Price
  FROM dbo.Prices gn  /*General price*/
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Prices rg /*Regional price*/
    ON rg.Product = @Product AND rg.Region = @Region AND rg.Store IS NULL
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Prices st  /*Store price*/
    ON rg.Product = @Product AND rg.Region = @Region AND rg.Store = @Store
  WHERE gn.Product = @Product
    AND gn.Region IS NULL AND gn.Store IS NULL
```

That way, you'll get the store price if that's not null, or the regional price if that's not null, or the general price if all else fails.

Comment: except if there is not default price (i.e. region null, store null) for a product

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I was looking for. The case for when even a general price is unavailable can be solved with another LEFT JOIN on the products table.

Comment: To clarify: This produces a price report when the Product clause is removed from the joins/where - or when joined normally on a products table.

Answer (score 4):

try this:
**EDIT** for all products, each listed once, even where given region and store do not exist...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPrice
     @Region int = null
    ,@Store int = null
AS

SELECT
    Product
        ,Region
        ,Store
        ,Price
    FROM (SELECT
              Product
                  ,Region AS Region
                  ,Store As Store
                  ,Price
                  ,Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY SortBy,Product,Region,Store,Price) AS RowNumber
              FROM (SELECT 1 AS SortBy,* FROM Prices WHERE (Region = @Region OR @Region IS NULL) AND (Store = @Store OR @Store IS NULL)
                    UNION
                    SELECT 2 AS SortBy,* FROM Prices WHERE (Region = @Region OR @Region IS NULL) 
                    UNION
                    SELECT 3 AS SortBy,* FROM Prices
                   ) Prices
         ) dt
    WHERE RowNumber=1
    ORDER BY Product

GO
```

Comment: This can return more than one price. It could be fixed using TOP(1) and an ORDER BY clause, but I'd like to get a list of only the most specific, effective prices for *all* my products, not just one.

Comment: Re top: Your version works as well (upvoted), but I find Brent's simpler to understand/adapt. It gives me the report I need if I join it as usual to the products table. I probably should have been a bit clearer when I said it's exactly what I want - I meant the general methodology.

Answer (score 1):

I think your data model might be a little screwy. Is the prices table being populated just for the report? I might review my tables, but if i had to use this setup, I would do something like this:

For product prices in a specified region (NOT STORE). Use this select in a sproc that accepts region as a parameter. If I did it right, it will return the region price, if there is one, and the product price, if there isn't.

Select Product, Price from dbo.prices where (Region = @region) or (region is NULL and product not in (select product from prices where region = @Region))

For product prices in a specified store. Use this select in a sproc that accepts store as a parameter. You will also need to pass in region or figure it out from the store. If I did it right, it will return the store price, if there is one, then he region price, then the product price.

Select product, price from dbo.prices where (store = @store) or (store is NULL AND region = @Region and product not in (select product from prices where store = @store) or (store is NULL and region is NULL and product not in (select product from prices where region = @Region))

To get prices from multiple regions or stores, just execute one of the above sprocs multiple times (in a loop or cursor).

Answer (score -1):

I guess this must work (didn't try it, though):

```
select top 1 price
from prices
where product = @product
and isnull(region, @region) = @region
and isnull(store, @store) = @store
order by region desc, store desc
```

A product must have least 1 Prices record. The ORDER BY .. DESC sorts original NULL values last.